# How can I insert a whole css class before an HTML element that I find?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to insert an image before an element I am trying to find in this code (also I am trying to add the class in the same function). 
 The js:

```
insertSearchIcon: function(){
    $(document).find('jstree-icon').prepend('<div class="oob-dropdown">test</div>');
    }
```

And the css class I am trying to insert.

```
.oob-dropdown {
  background-image: url("/apps/cdpe/img/search_444444.png");
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 1cm;
  position: relative;
}
```

Hopefully what I am trying to do is possible, but thanks for any help!

Comment: it's probably possible, it's just not understandable? Try to explain it a little differently, are you just trying to insert an element, the entire CSS, or something else completely, and what exactly isn't working ?

Comment: sorry haha, I guess I dont know the right terminology for everything. I want to put that .oob-dropdown before an element in the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably missed the `.` in your selector `find('jstree-icon')` and secondly `prepend()` adds another item before the first child element of the matched selector. 
To add another element right before another you might be interested in `before`:

`$('.jstree-icon').before('<div class="oob-dropdown">test</div>');`

Btw: `$(document).find()` is probably not best practice, rather use the selector directly!

Comment: tried it and still not seeing any results, when I put in <div class="oob-dropdown">, will it know that I am referring to the css object?

Comment: Who does `$(document).find(selector)` when `$(selector)` does the same thing? Best to advise on the correct way as well as fixing the typo :)

Comment: good point haha I wonder...could you just use the addclass function? Or that would probably break the code right?

Answer (score 2):

`.prepend()` inserts an element as the first child of another; it sounds like you need [`.before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before). Your selector also needs a dot (assuming `jstree-icon` is a class).

```
$('.jstree-icon').before('<div class="oob-dropdown">test</div>');
```